# Are all ports routable?

Tags: security, networking, tcp

Can I use private port numbers to expose a service like HTTP?
Are they dropped by routers like they drop private IP addresses?

I'm just asking out of curiosity.

I'm just wondering if there is a security implications to private port numbers?

E.g. if I want to open few private (internal) port numbers (e.g. 12000) in my internal network, will I be vulnerable security-wise?

Comment: There is no such thing as a private port number. Your question is therefore meaningless.

Comment: @EJP Private I mean `dynamic` not "well known" or "registered" .

Comment: Then say so. In your question. Not that it makes any difference. Still meaningless. All ports are equal except for purposes of RFC 1700 and successors, and routing isn't one of those purposes. Routers don't care about port numbers. Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, routing happens at L3 (ip) where there are just addresses, not ports.  ports are part of the L4 protocols (tcp/udp), so don't affect routing.

So there's no such thing as a standard 'private' port as far as routing or security is concerned.  You can program a router/firewall to examine L4 headers and drop packets for specific ports, thus making those ports effectively private, but that must generally be done on a per-router basis.  Get the router config wrong and you have a security hole.

So for your example, if you open port 12000 on some internal machine and don't program your router or firewall to block that specific port or specific machine, you'll be vulnerable.